# How to find element(as fast as possible) in List<WebElement>

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

can you, please, help me?

I have a List and its size about 200 elements. My code  is taking about 10 seconds to find right element(if it placed at the end of list). And i am seeking a faster way to find it. Thanks in advance(and sorry if i made rude mistakes in english)

```
for (int i = 0; i < ToRecObj.List.size(); i++) {            
        WebElement iter = ToRecObj.List.get(i);
        iter.click();
        String iterValue = iter.getText().trim();
        if (iterValue.equals(someStringForSearch)) {
            MainPage.SelectListField.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 10 seconds for searching 200 elements doesn't make sense. What does `iter.click()` do?

Comment: @Eran Additionally OP have a lot of CONSTANTS `MainPage`, `SelectListField` which may be adding significant delay. Perhaps this question doesn't fits into stackoverflow but in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: @Eran iter.click() is just for visualization. I can observe on page during test how it goes through every WebElement from List<WebElement>

Comment: @DebanjanB SelectListField works once when condition is true. Also when commented iter.click(); it takes same 8-10 sec to find.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `List.indexOf()` is what you are looking for. It returns the index of the first appearance of an element (if there are duplicates)
As you dont describe what the could should do and what the classes do i can only guess what you want to do:
You want to search all of your WebElements for a specific serch string.
With Java 8 you could do:

```
if(ToRecObj.List.stream().anyMatch(we -> we.getText().trim().equals(someStringForSearch)) {
   MainPage.SelectListField.click();
}
```

Using `anyMatch()` it will return true also if there is more than one match to your search string.

Comment: updated answer, try this please or clarify your question